# What's the recommended way to install the wall mounting spacer?

Tags: self-assembly-furniture

I'm building a besta cabinet. I'm following [the instructions](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/assembly_instructions/besta-frame__AA-1272080-4_pub.pdf).

I'm on step 8 (page 13). It says to push the spacers (item number 141413) into the holes. I got them in a tiny bit, but no matter how hard I push, it won't go in any further. It's like the holes aren't big enough.

I called ikea, and the person at the store didn't have any suggestions except watching videos online, and all of the besta videos I've seen don't have anything about this spacer, it looks like this is a new model, because the other videos have different things on the back.

I could probably rig something like a thick sheet of metal or something to give me a place to hammer against, but that seems like the wrong thing. What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to gently compress them in with pliers (ordinary slip joint or channel locks) or a clamp (e.g., a C-clamp).  Use a scrap of wood as a protector on the outside to prevent damage to the finish. You might have to alternate from one pin to the other until both are easier to push in. Do the pins or the holes have a means to avoid resistance from trapped air?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a trapped air problem, as I've only compressed the air a small amount, and it doesn't feel like it's compression pushing back, but maybe.

Comment: Does the center-to- center distance between the holes match that of the pins?  Are the holes too close to the back panel? Or is there proper alignment but the the holes appear to be too small? Have you tried pliers or a clamp?

Comment: I haven't tried pliers or a clamp; I didn't think I'd need those. It does seem like a good option though, so I'll try it, hopefully before this weekend is over.

Comment: If you don't have pliers that are large enough, you could **lay the shelves on one side** so the side is supported by the floor and try to force the pins in by pushing downward with your thumbs, or thrusting down with a rod, or even tapping with a hammer. Personally I think pliers would do, especially properly set locking pliers (aka Vise Grips of the right size).  Remember to protect the finish on the outside of the side panel.

Comment: Yeah, the thumbs are what I tried first.

Comment: I ended up using vice grips. They were the only "pliers" I had big enough. I protected the wood with a fake credit card American Express sends in the mail

Comment: So presumably you not only *used* the vise grip locking pliers, but that worked, right?  The spacers slid into place, right?

Comment: Correct. I used the vice grips, and that was what solved my problem. I wouldn't say they "slid", but more "stuttered", each notch on the item was a friction point.